# Help extracting data from JSON result

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue retrieving the key from this JSON result returned from the last.fm api

this is what is being returned:

```
{"session":{"name":"mcbeav","key":"***************","subscriber":"1"}}
```

and i just need the key, but if i try to print_r or var_dump , nothing is displayed how would i go about doing so?

for example if i `print_r($json['key']);` or if i `print_r['session']['key'];`

what is printed is "{";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use the php function

`$myJsonData = json_decode($myJsonString,true)`

it will give you an assocative array like you have in your code (what the second arguement true is for)

Hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: hahahah wow, i work with json all the time, flipping hardcore brain fart. thanks man i appreciate that. wow i feel stupid

Comment: We all have a few slip ups every now and then. (:

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = json_decode('{"session":{"name":"mcbeav","key":"eab5a0axxxxxxx0c3","subscriber":"1"}}');
echo $json->session->key;
```

Or if you want an array:

```
$json = json_decode('{"session":{"name":"mcbeav","key":"eab5a0axxxxxxx0c3","subscriber":"1"}}', true);
echo $json['session']['key'];
```